# Single producer to multi consumers (Same consumer group)

Tags: python, producer-consumer, kafka-python

I've try before sending message from single producer to 2 different consumer with **DIFFERENT** consumer group id. The result is both consumer able to read the complete message (both consumers getting the same message). But I would like to ask is it possible for these 2 consumers read different messages while setting them under a **SAME** consumer group name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer already, just make sure the partition number is not equal to one while creating new topic.